# Need Macro to move entire row record to new sheet based on duplicates found in one column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spread sheet with 3,000 records (rows) , there are multiple records that have duplicate info in one column. I'm hoping there is a macro out there that can move duplicate records found in this one row and move it to another sheet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it useful to read the following. [how-to-find-eliminate-or-use-duplicates-in-excel-data](https://www.pryor.com/blog/how-to-find-eliminate-or-use-duplicates-in-excel-data/)

You could just record your actions while performing one of the suggestions if you need a macro for future use. If you just want to remove the duplicates use the "Remove Duplicates" tool on the data tab. Otherwise, we would need a data sample to see exactly what you are needing.